# Onclick update with autosuggestion

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have created an autosuggestion to show results from a DB table when typing in an html field and I want to use javascript to post another value from the same row the values from the autosuggestions are in.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIhqK.png

Both those suggestions have their own numbers, they're not duplicates but on to what I need help with, I want the number in the row of anyone of these suggestions to post in the number's field below.

Here's the html form

```
                    <div class="floatingBox">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <form class="contentForm" form method="POST" form action="index.php">

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Name:*</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                      <input type="text" name="name" class="span4 autosuggest">
                                       <div class="control-group" >
                                       <div class="dropdown">
                                       <ul class="result"></ul></div>
                                    <label class="control-label">Number:*</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                      <input type="text" class="span4 number" name="number" placeholder="ex: ######">
                                    </div>
```

Here's the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.span4.autosuggest').keyup(function() {

    var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
    $.post('ajax/search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data){
        $('.result').html(data);

        $('.result li') .click(function() {

            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('.span4.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
            $('.result').html('');
            });


        });

    });
});
```

Here's the PHP that pulls the info from the database table

```
<?

include '../connect.php';

 if(isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false) {

$search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM *table* WHERE id = '$userid' AND name LIKE '$search_term%' ");

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false){

    echo '<li>', $row['client_name'], '</li>';
    }
} 

      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Emit JSON instead of HTML with your PHP. Then populate the fields with Javscript.

PHP (assuming the row containing the number is called "client_number")

```
<?

include '../connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false) {
   $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term']);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM *table* WHERE id = '$userid' AND name LIKE '$search_term%' ");

   $results = array();
   while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
     $results[] = array('client_name' => $row['client_name'], 'client_number' => $row['client_number']);
   }

   header("Content-Type: application/json");
   echo json_encode($results);
}

?>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.span4.autosuggest').keyup(function() {
     var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
     $.post('ajax/search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data){
        for(var k in data) {
          $('.result').append("<li data-number='"+data[k].client_number+"'>"+data[k].client_name+"</li>");
        }

        $('.result li') .click(function() {
           $('.span4.autosuggest').val($(this).text());
           $('.span4.number').val($(this).data("number"));
           $('.result').html('');
        });

      });

   });
});
```